# Can I fly to Cambodia and back to South Korea to catch my flight home to the US after my study abroad visa is over?

Tags: visas, air-travel, south-korea

I am studying abroad for 6 months in South Korea but I want to go to Cambodia to do a volunteer trip for two weeks at the end of school. However during the Cambodia program my student visa ends in the middle of the two weeks in Cambodia. My return flight to the USA is from South Korea. I may also have to stay the night at a hotel once I get back to South Korea, if I get back early (so I will need to leave the South Korean airport).

Can I fly to Cambodia and back to South Korea for a night with these problems to catch my flight home the next day without issues? Will the 90 days visa take the place of the student visa when I go back? Do I need to do something special? I will only be in South Korea for a night so I don't want to accidentally get in trouble.

Comment: I'm guessing you're a US citizen, if so you don't need visas to *visit* South Korea. I'm pretty certain you'll have no trouble going back to catch your flight. Immigration might ask you to prove you don't intend to stay, just show them proof of your flight to the US

Answer (score 2):

#### You're from a visa-free country

I'm assuming from your question you're a US citizen, if so you don't need to worry. You'll enter South Korea as a tourist and be granted 90 days which are ample time to leave. The immigration officer might ask you some questions, given your recent stay, to make sure you don't intend to remain there. Generally showing proof of onward travel (your ticket to the US) should be enough.

#### You're from a visa country and flying through Incheon

If you're from a country where a visa is required to enter South Korea, you may still be able to get in [without one](http://www.emirates.com/ca/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=US&NV=United+States&AC=KH&AV=Cambodia&DC=US&DV=United+States&TC=KR&TV=Korea&h=7ee5896dd9f2ba38b8e94636b1bc4757a6ebfd).

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   Seoul Incheon (ICN), for a max. transit time of 24 hours. Holders of
>   onward tickets transiting Seoul Incheon (ICN), participating in the
>   Transit Tourism Program for a max. transit time of 72 hours.